# poedit doesn't translate all strings

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I'm using poedit to translate a WP site. Strangely enough most strings translate correct, but a few don't. For example, << vorig artikel (Dutch, correctly translated) next to Next Article >> (the original English, not translated). No matter what I try, it remains as it is: a sloppy translation.

The string Next Article is

```
Next Article>>>>>>> .r11
```

It doesn't make any difference if I translate that in

```
volgend artikel
```

or in

```
volgend artikel>>>>>>> .r11
```

I'm using poedit on Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

It's impossible to say because you don't really describe what you're *doing*. The only reasonably certain thing is that this is not Poedit doing something wrong, but some mistake elsewhere. Poedit doesn't just randomly omit some strings but not others, that wouldn't make any sense.

It can be one of the following:

1. You didn't actually translate the entry in question.
2. You did, but marked it as fuzzy, meaning "needs review", meaning it isn't compiled into the MO file.
3. You forgot to copy an update MO file to the server.
4. You copied it to a wrong place, so an older version is used instead.
5. You use some caching plugin and didn't refresh your browser.
6. It could even be a bug in the theme/plugin (you don't even say which it is) in question where that specific string is untranslatable.
7. It could be something else that you left out.